# Networking for Xna (C#) and C++?

Tags: c#, c++, networking, xna, winsock

Me and some friends were thinking about making an online game with XNA game studio. Our games mainly used Winsock for the networking portion, but our most recent project used RakNet where the server was in C++ and the Client used a small RakNet wrapper I wrote. As far as I know XNA can't really use DLLs, so I was wondering what a good networking solution would be.

1) C# already has some networking capabilities, but would it be a bad idea to write a server in C#. I've primarily used C++ for the raw power it has.

2) If it's a bad idea to write server in C#, are their any libraries that will work with C++ and C#? Or maybe I could just use the C# networking for the client, and Winsock for the server (if they are compatible.. I assume C# uses standard TCP layers..)?

Hopefully you guys have some suggestions for networking options.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XNA on Windows can do anything .NET applications can do. XNA on Xbox/Zune/Windows Phone 7 are more restricted and won't run unmanaged DLLs. (Managed DLLs are still supported)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with writing a server in C#.
The open source MMORPG software that simulates a Ultima Online server, RunUO, runs in C# with good results.

Yes, Winsock and C# Sockets are compatible.